# Convert Json String to Json in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm newbie with NewtonJson,i have a problem so i believe it very easy  to solve it, but i cant not found solution at now. My problem is :

I have  a json string like that :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "returnData": {
        "rateInfos": [
            {
                "ctm": 1595872800000,
                "ctmString": "Jul 27, 2020 8:00:00 PM",
                "open": 117551,
                "close": 35,
                "high": 43,
                "low": 0,
                "vol": 5428
            },
            {
                "ctm": 1595873100000,
                "ctmString": "Jul 27, 2020 8:05:00 PM",
                "open": 117588,
                "close": -8,
                "high": 15,
                "low": -8,
                "vol": 3326
            }
            
        ],
        "digits": 5,
        "exemode": 1
    }
}
```

I want to get value of "rateInfos" by :

```
            string h = chart.ReturnData.ToString();
            //h is string above
            dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(h);
            foreach (var item in dynObj.rateInfos)
            {

                foreach (var item1 in item)
                {
                    
                   
                }

            }
```

But i really can get value of rateInfos follow block {},{}..
Do you have any ideas on this case?
Thanks !

Comment: take a look at your json data. specifically, at the structure. your root object does **not** contain a property `rateInfos` - it contains a property `returnData`, which contains `rateInfos`. try accessing that. the best way however: define your data structure as classes _in your code_, so you can deserialise to a **strongly typed** object.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, try this code:

```
string json = @"{
"status": true,
"returnData": {
    "rateInfos": [
        {
            "ctm": 1595872800000,
            "ctmString": "Jul 27, 2020 8:00:00 PM",
            "open": 117551,
            "close": 35,
            "high": 43,
            "low": 0,
            "vol": 5428
        },
        {
            "ctm": 1595873100000,
            "ctmString": "Jul 27, 2020 8:05:00 PM",
            "open": 117588,
            "close": -8,
            "high": 15,
            "low": -8,
            "vol": 3326
        }
        
    ],
    "digits": 5,
    "exemode": 1
}
}";
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in result["returnData"]["rateInfos"])
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", item.ctm, item.ctmString, item.open, item.close, item.high, item.low, item.vol);
}
```

Comment: Yes, dynamic is powerful and in this case makes things very very easy. Please, 
if you can mark the answer as valid I'd really appreciate that. Have a nice day :)